# HOW can I add a sort row column?

Tags: oracle, sorting, plsql, product, rank

Im using view on oracle plsql. In the table showing my sales,
I want to have a column showing the sequence number next to the sales of  top 50 products.

The best selling products should be listed and followed by the sequence number in the row.

how can i do that?

Thanks.

This is my related query

```
 NVL (
                             (SELECT ROUND (
                                        SUM (
                                           CASE DOCUMENT_TYPE
                                              WHEN 2
                                              THEN
                                                 (CASE TRANSACTION_TYPE
                                                     WHEN 0 THEN 0 - AMOUNT
                                                     ELSE AMOUNT
                                                  END)
                                              ELSE
                                                 (CASE TRANSACTION_TYPE
                                                     WHEN 1 THEN 0 - AMOUNT
                                                     ELSE AMOUNT
                                                  END)
                                           END),
                                        8)
                                FROM TBL_TRANSACTION_LINES
                               WHERE     STORE_NO = tbl_location.locationno
                                     AND (TRANSACTION_TYPE NOT IN (10, 30))
                                     AND TRANSACTION_DATE >
                                            TO_DATE ('2020-09-27 0:0:0',
                                                     'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')
                                     AND TRANSACTION_DATE <=
                                            TO_DATE ('2020-10-04 0:0:0',
                                                     'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')
                                     AND (URUNID = TBL_URUNLER.URUNID)),
                             0)
                             AS RESULTS
```

Comment: No. You shared part of a query that is concerned with whether you need the value in an amount column, the negative of that column or 0. But at least from what is shown that has nothing to do with your question. Please post the full query, table definitions, and sample data - as text, ** no images**. Additionally post the expected results of the test data, also as text. You may want to take a look at [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your tables nor data, so - here's an example based on Scott's sample schema; ranking employees by salary within their departments. Apply that to your case.

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select deptno, ename, sal,
  3       rank() over (partition by deptno order by sal desc) rnk
  4     from emp
  5    )
  6  select deptno, ename, sal, rnk
  7  from temp
  8  order by deptno, rnk;

    DEPTNO ENAME             SAL        RNK
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10 KING            10000          1
        10 CLARK            2450          2
        10 MILLER           1300          3
        20 SCOTT            3000          1
        20 FORD             3000          1
        20 JONES            2975          3
        20 ADAMS            1100          4
        20 SMITH             920          5
        30 BLAKE            2850          1
        30 ALLEN            1600          2
        30 TURNER           1500          3
        30 MARTIN           1250          4
        30 WARD             1250          4
        30 JAMES             950          6

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```